# How to create default database in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to Create default database in SQ-Lite database? so if the Database/Value doesn't exist i want my App to use default Database/Value automatically..

Here is my database creation code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("D5",MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Record(value1 VARCHAR,value2 VARCHAR,value3 VARCHAR);");


}
```

Comment: are you talking about a pre-populated db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i usually do is a class similar to this...

```
public class SQLiteAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
private static String DATABASE_NAME="your_database_name";

public SQLiteAdapter(Context context){
   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Record(value1 VARCHAR,value2 VARCHAR,value3 VARCHAR);");
     }
 }
```

then when you want to use it from an activity:

```
SQLiteAdapter db;    

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
}
```

and with that instance db you can do whatever you want, db.execSQL, etc. etc.